# IDE thinks functor is a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, functor

I am trying to write an implementation of primms algorithm for a DSA class. There are some nuances to make the project a little trickier (some points cannot be reached by others based on the 'terrain' at that location) so I made a functor to get distances (edge weights). My functor looks like this

```
class primms_distance{
            double operator ()(const primms_vertex &a, const primms_vertex &b){
                //ommitted for University honor code purposes
            }
        };
```

However, I later do the following (again simplified for honor code purposes)

```
primms_vertex temp = priority_queue.top();
priority_queue.pop();
for(primms_vertex a : primms_vector){
    if(omitted && primms_vertex::primms_distance(a, temp) < a.distance)
}
```

This call to primms distance gets me the error 'no matching constructor for initialization of 'primms_vertex::primms_distance'. Does anyone know why this is happening? The functor is clearly defined as 'double operator ()' so Im not sure why this is happening, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need `primms_vertex::primms_distance()(a, temp)` to create an instance, *then* call it.

Comment: `primms_distance` is a type, `primms_distance()` is an object.  `primms_distance(xxx)` calls the constructor, `primms_distance()(xxx)` calls the operator().

Comment: guys, what do these comments tell that isnt already in an answer, or should belong in another one?

Answer (score 2):

You need an object to call a non-static member function. The compiler is right in expecting a call to the constructor first. Try this:

```
primms_vertex::primms_distance()(a, temp)
                            //^ constructor
                            //   ^ operator()
```

Comment: Okay, I usually always use these in sorts or queues to return bools so I've never had to use one on its own yet. That makes perfect sense though, thank you!

Comment: @doubleflowseven when passing functor to `std::sort` you would also need to create an instance